# Update M2M value after model_save

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have an model called Contact that has a M2M relationship called tags. The model has a couple of booleanfields (in this example student, alumus and employee).

I want to achieve the following:
After each save of an Contact object, I want to check if for each booleanfield, a tags relationship exists. If it doesn't exist, it should be added.

I thought that this would work with a post_save hook, this is my code:

**models.py**

```
class Contact(BaseModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    alumnus = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    employee = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

def update_tag(instance, tag_name, tagged):
    tag, created = Tag.objects.get_or_create(name=tag_name, defaults={'deletable': False})
    if tagged:
        instance.tags.add(tag)
    else:
        instance.tags.remove(tag)
    
@receiver(post_save, sender=Contact, dispatch_uid="update_tags")
def update_tags(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    update_tag(instance, "Alumni", instance.alumnus)
    update_tag(instance, "Students", instance.student)
    update_tag(instance, "Employees", instance.employee)
```

I noticed however that this only works if I don't include my tags field in the ModelForm object. If it is included, all updates are ignored. If it isn't included, everything works as expected.

I did some research and [found](http://timonweb.com/posts/many-to-many-field-save-method-and-the-django-admin/) that apparently m2m relationships are quite different:

> When you save a model via admin forms it's not an atomic transaction.
> The main object gets saved first (to make sure it has a PK), then the
> M2M is cleared and the new values set to whatever came out of the
> form. So if you are in the save() of the main object you are in a
> window of opportunity where the M2M hasn't been updated yet. In fact,
> if you try to do something to the M2M, the change will get wiped out
> by the clear().

However, since I am not using the admin form, I don't understand why this also occurs in my case. Does anybody know how I can solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not just in admin forms, this happens for when you save any Django model  anywhere.

I'm not finding any good doc links to the "why", but I believe it has to do with the database structure. In Django it's stored in a single model, but on the database level it creates an intermediate table between `Contact` and `Tag` (which is the proper way to do it on the database level) - it's just hidden when inside Django.

Instead of using the `post_save` signal, you need to use [m2m_changed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/signals/#m2m-changed) signal, which will fire when the ManyToMany field is changed.

Comment: But the problem is that I want to check, after each model save, if the boolean fields are changed. If these boolean fields are changed, I want to "sync" the m2m field. So m2m_changed wouldn't work in my case.

Comment: What solution did you end up implementing for this?